# Angular format input value as date with modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an input that accepts the datetime picker as an option. Now when choosing a date it shows correctly.

When loading the date in when say the user presses an edit button from one of the entries the date shows incorrect as format (Don't know the name of the date format):

```
Thu Oct 09 2014 05:06:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)
```

My code is as such, my mission is to format the date on the input no matter how it's loaded.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{'dd-MMMM-yyyy'}}" ng-model="{{startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" is-open="openedStart" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

Comment: As far as i know, you cannot use interpolations and filters in an ng-model, ng-model needs to be a property that can be assigned to.

Comment: How would you suggest I handle this? Format the modal it's self?

Comment: I think there must be some settings in the datepicker to specify the format to display, i have not used bs datepicker much.

Comment: There is, but when loading modals it shows the wrong format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="startDate" is-open="openedStart" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```